# VBA: how to create a new array showing the calculated averages for each column in another array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, average

I´m new to VBA and Stack Overflow, apologies for any clumsiness.

Per below code I generate Array1 of random values of a size specified by the user via Input Boxes. Array1 is then output to worksheet for testing purposes. I´m minimizing interactions with the worksheet for speed reasons.

Question: how do I calculate an average for each column of Array1 (these averages feeding into a to-be-created Array2, measuring 1 row and same width as the number of columns in Array1)? Calculations strictly done in memory and not in the worksheet. An average for each column separately. And then pasting these Array2 results into the second empty row just beneath where Array1 was pasted in the worksheet? (You´ll see the Array1 pasting starts on Cell A1 and spreads down/right from there).

I´ve researched and tried with no luck. Easy inputs for running below code (which is working fine fine for me) are 10 rows, 2 columns, alpha = 1, beta = 1

```
Sub MC()

'   Clear contents of active worksheet
    Cells.Clear

'   Moves cursor to starting point
    Range("A1").Select

'   Declarations of variables and arrays
    Dim CellsDown As Long, CellsAcross As Long
    Dim Alpha As Double, Beta As Double
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer
    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim Array1() As Double
    Dim OutputSim As Range
     
'   Set array dimensions and other inputs for running Monte Carlo
    CellsDown = InputBox("How many rows?")
        If CellsDown = 0 Then Exit Sub
    CellsAcross = InputBox("How many columns?")
        If CellsAcross = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Alpha = InputBox("Distribution shape alpha value?")
        If Alpha <= 0 Then Exit Sub
    Beta = InputBox("Distribution shape beta value?")
        If Beta <= 0 Then Exit Sub
    
'   Record starting time
    StartTime = Timer
     
'   Redimension array
    ReDim Array1(1 To CellsDown, 1 To CellsAcross)
   
'   Set worksheet range
    Set OutputSim = ActiveCell.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(CellsDown, CellsAcross))
  
'   Fill array1 with random values generated from inverse of cumulative beta probability density function
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For i = 1 To CellsDown
        For j = 1 To CellsAcross
            Randomize
            Array1(i, j) = Application.Beta_Inv(Application.RandBetween(0.0000001, 100 - 0.0000001) / 100, Alpha, Beta, 0, 1)
        Next j
    Next i

'   Transfer array1 to worksheet
    OutputSim.Value = Array1
  
'   Display elapsed time
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox Format(Timer - StartTime, "00.00") & " seconds"
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, insert the next piece of code after `Array1` loading loop:

```
'Fill the average array:____________________________________________________________________
 Dim arrAv, arrCol
 
 ReDim arrAv(CellsAcross - 1)       '1D array to keep the columns average
 For i = 0 To UBound(Array1, 2) - 1 'iterate between the array columns
    arrCol = Application.index(Array1, 0, i + 1) 'obtain a column slice from Array1
    arrAv(i) = WorksheetFunction.Average(arrCol) 'fill the array element with the Average
 Next i
 'drop the array content at two columns to the right of OutputSim:
 OutputSim.Offset(0, 2 + OutputSim.Columns.count).Resize(1, UBound(arrAv) + 1).Value = arrAv
'____________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Thank you very much! A perfect and straight-forward solution. Only very minor difference is per my original ask above I was trying to place the new Array2 averages 2 rows beneath the last row of Array1 that is pasted into the Worksheet, and your solution places the Array2 averages 2 columns to the right of the pasted Array1. Which is much better than my original attempt, it´s more readable, thank you for improving this!

Comment: @Lil' Lou - user9788072: Glad I could help! I though it is better in the way I designed the code, but if you need to  be placed where you requested, the last code line can be transformed in `OutputSim.Offset(1 + OutputSim.Rows.count, 0).Resize(1, UBound(arrAv) + 1).Value = arrAv`...